# javascript: ajax call not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a javascript file which sends lat and lon to database, calling insertLocation.php

the file path is proj/services/insertlocation (I don't know if I have the right path)

```
function updateLocation(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/services/insertLocation.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                lat: $lat,
                lon: $lon,
                userid: 0
            }
        }).done(function(data){
            alert("data saved");
        });
    }
```

the insertLocation.php works fine when ran independantly

Any ideas?

Comment: check for errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and view your console

Comment: Did you check your error on console??

Comment: if $lat and $lon are php variables then how they will print the way you are doing ?

Comment: as @UmairKhan said check your vars $lat and $lon also check your url /services/insertLocation.php may be could be services/insertLocation.php

Comment: yes these two things if corrected then can get the required result

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to add a fail in your ajax:

```
.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```